# How to use Libraries

Tags: c++, windows, macos

For some reason I'm never able to use external libraries in any language. I'm looking for instructions/explanations of how to use external libraries, as well as how they work. When I search online, I get fragments that never seem to apply to whatever library I download and try and use. I work on both a mac and a pc, and C++ examples are fine. I use eclipse IDE with the C++ plug in. If there are instructions that apply to all libraries that would be great.

Comment: When you do `std::cout << "Hello World";` you are using a library. Could you be more specific?

Comment: Your last question involved #include <iostream> so you've used them to some extent no?  You're question is pretty open ended, try something specific and then ask a question about that.

Comment: I think my question reveals how little I know of programming. I mean libraries that aren't built in to the language (if that makes any sense).

Comment: Libraries that are do not come as part of a language are typically called "Third Party Libraries"

Comment: Please don't ask for a tutorial. You should ask a specific question for a particular programming problem. Since Stack Overflow hides the Close reason from you: *"Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it."*

Answer (score 238, accepted):

Say you have a class `Unuseful` defined as follows:

File `Unuseful.h`:

```
class Unuseful {
public:
    void printUnusefulStatement();
};
```

File `Unuseful.cpp`:

```
#include "unuseful.h"
#include <iostream>

void Unuseful::printUnusefulStatement()
{
    std::cout << "Hello world!" << std::endl;
}
```

Now, you have another class that needs printing unuseful statements:

```
Unuseful u;
u.printUnusefulStatement();
```

This means that you want to use an external library containing the specific implementation (`printUnusefulStatement`) that you want to include in your code.

You may use this library in two ways:

1. By providing the source code to the compiler
2. By providing a binary file (which had been previously compiled for your architecture), to the linker

### Case 1: using a library at compile time

This is the simplest case.
You have the source code of the library you have to use and you simply have to compile it together with your existing code (say `main.cpp` file).
Typically you are the author and user of the library (a class that accomplishes a task you need).

Compiling with this command:

```
g++ main.cpp unuseful.cpp
```

allows you to use the implementation you need in your `main.cpp` file.

### Case 2: linking a library

More often than *Case 1*, you don't have the source code of the library you want to use. You only have the header file (`Unuseful.h`, to continue with the example) and a **static** or **shared** library (probably[*] `libunuseful.a` and `libunuseful.so` files, respectively).

The static library is an archive of object files (`*.o`) that are linked inside your final executables, the shared libraries instead are loaded dynamically - at run time (look at [this page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Library_%28computing%29) for a better understanding of the difference).

Static libraries are created by simply archiving the `*.o` files with the `ar` program:

```
# Create the object files (only one here)
g++ -c unuseful.cpp
# Create the archive (insert the lib prefix)
ar rcs libunuseful.a unuseful.o
```

Shared libraries are created with the `g++` `-shared` option:

```
# Create the object file with Position Independent Code[**]
g++ -fPIC -c unuseful.cpp
# Crate the shared library (insert the lib prefix)
g++ -shared -o libunuseful.so unuseful.o
```

Let's suppose now you have the `Unuseful.h` file and the shared library (`libunuseful.so` file) and you have a `main.cpp` file that instantiates a `Unuseful` object and calls the `printUnusefulStatement` method.

If you try to compile this file (`g++ main.cpp`) the linker will complain because it cannot find the `printUnusefulStatement` symbol.

It's time to use the library:

```
g++ main.cpp -L. -lunuseful
```

The `-L` option tells the linker where to search for library files and the `-l` flag tells the linker the name of the libraries to be used (without the `lib` prefix).

Now the executable (`a.out`, because I didn't specify a different name) is created, and you have used a library to implement a functionality you needed (`printUnusefulStatement`).

Since the shared library is loaded at run-time, the execution of the `a.out` executable may fail because the system is not able to find the library.
Typically this can be solved by appropriately setting an environment variable indicating which paths to use to search for dynamic libraries:

```
# Set the LD_LIBRARY_PATH [*]
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:.
```

Done, now your executable has been compiled and it will be able to run and load the library it needs.

### Conclusion

This is a rapid overview on libraries which I hope can help you understand how they are used and provided to others.

There are many many aspects that should be investigated in more detail, if you are interested: `g++` options when creating shared libraries, `ar` options, environment variables, the shared libraries format and so on.

<sub>[*]: In a Unix environment</sub>

<sub>[**]: If supported for the target machine, emit position-independent code, suitable for dynamic linking and avoiding any limit on the size of the global offset table. This option makes a difference on the m68k, PowerPC and SPARC. Position-independent code requires special support, and therefore works only on certain machines. *[From the g++ man page]*</sub>

Comment: just found this...thanks so much for this clear explanation. I had the overall process but the little details were messing me up

Comment: cool explanations. Just curious regarding this command `g++ main.cpp -L. -lunuseful`, why is there no space after `-L` and why `-lunuseful` instead of using full name`-llibunuseful`. Is there any legacy reasons, because it makes that so confusing  for starters.

Answer (score 7):

Here's where you start
[http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Library_(computing)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Library_(computing))

Basically, a 'library' is a collection of compiled functions and class declarations.

On a Mac there are also "frameworks" which are somewhat similar to Pascal's units and contain both the declarations and the compiled code.

In managed languages like Java or C# there are packages and assemblies. Both are closely related to libraries.

To use libraries in C or C++ you've got to have a .lib-file (or .a-file for most POSIX or GCC toolchain based compilers) and the prototypes of the functions which are compiled into the .lib file. Depending on your development environment (for Eclipse you are most likely using the GCC compiler and GNU toolchain with LD linker), you just specify the library files (.lib or .a) as the input to the linker. Most of the time the library is accompanied with header files which contain the definitions of function prototypes.

Even if you did not know about the linker, which is strange enough, the libraries are still used in your program implicitly - the std::cout is in the libstdc++ or the C Run-Time Library.

As an example of a huge library and a useful set of C++ classes you might want to look at Boost.

To write GUI on Windows you can use the WinAPI which is described in MSDN.

To write GUI on Mac you can use Carbon API which is somewhat similar to WinAPI, but is now deprecated. The only way to write "legit" GUI for MacOS is to use Cocoa and Objective-C.

To write cross-platform GUI you can use a lot of libraries: Qt, wxWidgets, GTK among them.

The last, but not the least. C++ is not the best language for GUI.

Comment: That last point is a bit debatable, best != easiest, alot of serious UIs are still written in C++.  All the browsers are for example, including Chrome which is new and had pleanty of alternatives when it was designed.

Comment: OK. I agree. It all depends. When portability comes to mind, not much to think about but C/C++. However, the front-end may be implemented in a platform-specific manner and C++ can be used for all of the business logic.

Comment: The last one you said as if we could use another language to write GUI and C++ is only used for core? How come?

Answer (score 3):

The best way to use external C++ libraries is make use of a C++ package manager, go and learn one of these:

- [conan](https://conan.io/)
- [vcpkg](https://vcpkg.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)
- [hunter](https://github.com/ruslo/hunter)
- [cppan](https://cppan.org/)
- [build2](https://build2.org/)

Some of them involve using CMake, you can find a well written tutorial on it [here](https://cliutils.gitlab.io/modern-cmake/).

.